How set an autoreload on my `socketio.ASGIapp` plugged on my FastAPI app?
I have an app combining FastAPI and SocketIO ASGI. On code change, the FastAPI reloads but not the SocketIO one. Is there a way to tell SocketIO to reload on change without using watchdog ? By setting a flag or something very short to write than a watchdog command ?
from fastapi import FastAPI
import socketio


fastapi_app = FastAPI()

app = socketio.ASGIApp(sio, fastapi_app)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn

    uvicorn.run("app.main:app", host="127.0.0.1", port=8888, log_level="debug", reload=True)


I think this would be a question for uvicorn. I don't know how they implemented their reload feature but I don't understand why it sees some files and not others. From the Socket.IO side there is no support for reloading, this is a function of web servers, which Socket.IO isn't.

Alright then. I just added WatchFiles in the command that runs the Celery app instead.
